# Out of this list of four fields, which two are equal: $\Bbb Q[ \sqrt{20}]$, $\Bbb Q[\sqrt{10}]$, $\Bbb Q[ \sqrt2,\sqrt5]$, $\Bbb Q[ \sqrt2+\sqrt5]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

What I have so far is: 
$$ 
\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt{20}] = \Bbb{Q}[ √ 5] = \Bbb{Q}[ \sqrt4\cdot\sqrt5] = \Bbb{Q}[ 2\cdot\sqrt5].$$
$$\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt2+ \sqrt5] \implies 
(\sqrt2+ \sqrt5)^2 = 7 + 2\sqrt{10}$$  so $\sqrt{10}$ is in $\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt2+ \sqrt5]$.
Also, $$\sqrt{10}(\sqrt2+\sqrt5) = 2\sqrt5 + 5\sqrt2,$$ so $\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt2, \sqrt5]$ is in $\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt2+ \sqrt5]$.

Is this sufficient to say that $\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt2+ \sqrt5]$ and $\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt2,\sqrt5]$ are the same ?

Thank you

Comment: None of the fields appearing in your question are finite, so I removed that tag. I also TeXified it a bit. Do take a look and learn to use it. Looks way better (at least when more complicated formulas are used).

Answer (score 0):

To answer your last question, yes. To check whether they are equal you want to determine whether the root you are adjoining has the same number of conjugates over the field your are extending.